# Which person of them do you know?

Tags: pronouns

If we have no list of choice, we say:

> What thing do you know?

If the list of choice appears, for example "of these ones", we change "what" for "which":

> Which thing of these ones do you know?

But what to do if we deal with alive nouns?

An example without the choice list:

> What person do you know?

What if we add "of them". Does "what" have a variant for the choice of list for alive nouns like "which" for not alive ones or it would be "which' anyway?

> Which person of them do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of “what person” or “which person” you can use “who” or “whom”:

> Whom do you know?
>
> Who of them do you know?
>
> Who of the following people do you know?

Comment: "Which person of them do you know?" is incorrect?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko that sounds awkward to me, even if it might be technically grammatical. “Which person” is equivalent to “who” and “who” would be much more likely to be used in a question like this.